# Website refreshing randomly with an unknown parameter &mn

Tags: javascript, html, sitecore

My website is refreshing randomly by itself with an additional unknown URL parameter `?mn` followed by a Hash. Example:
`?mn=l4ehjinilk0ids2leotmtyrmttfuq4oqedu.eebubnay47ddfhvd`

I really don't know where it comes from. It happened even in Incognito mode.

Website is on Sitecore.

Any ideas?

Comment: Any extensions enabled? What does your website do? Really hard to say anything without  seeing your website's code.

Comment: That might be a cacheblocker.

Comment: Consider adding more details? Who is the hosting provider? How is the website made? Do you have an example?

Comment: @LW001 I see it happens in Incognito mode, browser extension was that was my first guess.

Comment: your wordpress probably got hacked

Comment: Either there's something wrong with the server or it's some sort of extension, do note extensions *can* run in incognito mode if it's enabled for the extension. Whatever it is, it's hard to tell without details about the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.
I finally found out.
It was due to the Zoom application, a **Post-attendee** URL was set, as soon as a meeting is done, Zoom triggers the default browser and redirects to a website.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30142383)

Answer (score 3):

If the page is loading correctly from the server but then refreshes with additional parameters in your browser, it must be triggered by JavaScript code. It can be caused by your own JavaScript, scripts injected by a third-party snippet, scripts executed by your browser extensions and so on.

Follow the steps below to find what triggers this refresh:

- Open *Developer Tools* in your browser and navigate to the *Network* tab
- Select the *Preserve log* checkbox
- Reload your web page to replicate the issue
- Find the request with parameter `?mn=` and select it
- Go to the *Initiator* tab, it will show the request call stack or request initiator chain similar to this:

[image: Request initiator]

This can help you understand what in your browser triggered the web page refresh.

Comment: Thanks you Anna !